@node-rs/argon2 module could not be found in Next.js
I am trying to implement username and password login with lucia and like in the lucia tutorial I am using @node-rs/argon2 for hashing passwords but I am getting this error:
Error: The specified module could not be found. ?\D:\Coding\social_app\node_modules@node-rs\argon2-win32-x64-msvc\argon2.win32-x64-msvc.node

My next.config.mgs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  serverExternalPackages: ['@node-rs/argon2'],
};

export default nextConfig;

I tried to reinstall all dependencies, updated node and npm to the latest version but it didn't help. Next.js version 15.0.0-rc.0.
